# Parse int to 0 Text if it is Alphabet String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following code. How can I convert alphabetical strings to `0` in sum up of `li` text values?

```js
var banner = $("#sum");
var button = $("button");

button.on("click", function() {
  var a = 0;
  $("li").each(function() {
    a += parseInt($(this).text());
  });
  banner.text(a);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sum">
  <p>Price</p>
  <button>Get Sum</button>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>85</li>
  <li>65</li>
  <li>Not Selected</li>
  <li>Not Selected</li>
  <li>15</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [isNumeric() function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.isnumeric/) to weed out the text:

```js
var banner = $("#sum");
var button = $("button");

button.on("click", function() {
  var a = 0;
  $("li").each(function() {
    if ($.isNumeric($(this).text())) a += parseInt($(this).text());
  });
  banner.text(a);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sum">
  <p>Price</p>
  <button>Get Sum</button>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>85</li>
  <li>65</li>
  <li>Not Selected</li>
  <li>Not Selected</li>
  <li>15</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

do a NaN Check

```
var banner = $("#sum");
var button = $("button");

button.on("click", function() {
  var a = 0;
  var temp = 0;
  $("li").each(function() {
    temp = parseInt($(this).text());
    if(temp !== NaN)
        a += temp;
  });
  banner.text(a);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has a built in method call isNan(). It returns a boolean value.

```
button.on("click", function() {
  var a = 0;
  $("li").each(function() {
    b = parseInt($(this).text());
    isNaN(b) ? console.log("Not a number") : a+=b
  });
  banner.text(a);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Double `~` (bitwise `NOT`) does the trick:

```js
var banner = $("#sum");
var button = $("button");

button.on("click", function() {
  var a = 0;
  $("li").each(function() {
    a += ~~$(this).text();
  });
  banner.text(a);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sum">
  <p>Price</p>
  <button>Get Sum</button>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>85</li>
  <li>65</li>
  <li>Not Selected</li>
  <li>Not Selected</li>
  <li>15</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a vanilla JS solution, you could use `isNaN` to check whether the string is not a number and return `0`, e.g.

```
  $("li").each(function() {
    const num = $(this).text();

    a += parseInt(isNaN(num) ? 0 : num);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [NaN is a falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) in `Javascript` and [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) returns and integer or `NaN` you can do:

```
a += parseInt($(this).text(), 10) || 0;
```

Note also, I have defined the `radix` argument to `10`, there is a good explanation on the [description of parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description) of why is good to the define the `radix` to avoid unexpected behaviors.

```js
var banner = $("#sum");
var button = $("button");

button.on("click", function()
{
    var a = 0;

    $("li").each(function()
    {
        a += parseInt($(this).text(), 10) || 0;
    });

    banner.text(a);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sum">
  <p>Price</p>
  <button>Get Sum</button>
</div>

<ul>
  <li>85</li>
  <li>65</li>
  <li>Not Selected</li>
  <li>Not Selected</li>
  <li>15</li>
</ul>
```